Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory does not support Managed Identity Authrization Credentials
I am using the following code, how to change this for Managed Identity based credentials S360 for Safe Secret (Remove password in apps)
public partial class Startup
{

    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];

    private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];

    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];

    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];

    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.

    string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)

    {

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(

            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions

            {

                ClientId = clientId,

                Authority = Authority,

                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()

                {

                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.

                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>

                    {

                        var code = context.Code;

                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));

                        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(

                        code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                        // AccountHelper.token = result.AccessToken;

                        return Task.FromResult(0);

                    }

                },

                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters

                {

                    ValidateIssuer = false,

                    ValidAudience = clientId,

                }


            });

    }

}

}
tried to work according to the approach provided in the doc but does not work.cannot use the Async with the current code. tried Azure.Core for token generation but that is not supported by the authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId); function.

Are you trying to generate access token for Microsoft Graph resource using managed identity authentication?

yes I was using an autofill username feature using  api from AAD now need that same functionality using Microsoft Graph
